# setting up Backbone with yarn

Tags: backbone.js, yarnpkg

I recently added various libraries with `yarn` like so:

```
yarn add jquery backbone underscore bootstrap
```

With `bower` there was a way to list out the paths that each of these libraries was in, how do I do this with `yarn`?

`yarn list --paths` only gives me the names of the libraries and the version number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to utilize `yarn` the way `bower` used to work, but `yarn list --paths` will only give you the dependencies and version number as you noted.

I think what you need to understand is that you are not using `bower_components`, you are using `node_modules`. With that said, your paths are probably something like `/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`. Open your `node_modules` folder and you will see what I am talking about.